# PHP mail with PHPMailer through Google SMTP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am really hoping one of you can help me.  I've been pulling my hair out for about 2 hours with this.  One of the accounts on my client's email servers got compromised and Google start blocking attempts for us to send emails.  So I am trying to switch from the basic PHP mail command to PHPMailer and send through Google's SMTP server.  This client uses Google Pro for all of his accounts.

I am using the following:

```
    $mail             = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->isSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the server
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "no-reply@mydomain.com";  // GMAIL username
    $mail->Password   = "*********";            // GMAIL password

    $mail->SetFrom('no-reply@mydomain.com', 'Jimmy');

    $mail->Subject    = $this->subject;

    $body             = $this->message;
    //$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);          

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->AddAddress($this->to, 'bob');

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        error_log("Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        echo '[br /]Fail';
    } else {
        error_log("Message sent!");
        echo '[br /]Pass';
    }
```

I know the credentials are correct because I can login with them.  I've done all kinds of stuff to this script and the account it is trying to use to send:

1. Change from TLS to SSL
2. 'unblock captcha' in the account
3. disabled 2 factor auth (it was already off)
4. enabled 'less secure apps'

I'm not sure what else to do.  This is the error I keep getting:

```
2017-05-15 03:12:30   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO americanbeautytools.com
2017-05-15 03:12:30   CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-05-15 03:12:30   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO americanbeautytools.com
2017-05-15 03:12:30   CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2017-05-15 03:12:30   CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx=
2017-05-15 03:12:30   CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx=
2017-05-15 03:12:32   SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data
2017-05-15 03:12:32   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2017-05-15 03:12:32   CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-05-15 03:12:32   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

The part about password command failed is the part I don't get.  How can that be wrong when I login with that email account just fine?

I have looked at about 15 of the threads on this topic and none of what they suggest solves my problem.  This is a google pro account that my client runs through google so it wouldn't be the 'free' restriction thing.

Comment: Pretty much *every one* of those threads you found, *and* the troubleshooting guide, will tell you to **set `SMTPDebug = 2`**. With it set to 1, you're not going to see anything that the server says.

Comment: If you'd based your code on the gmail example provided with PHPMailer, you wouldn't have got into this difficulty in the first place.

Comment: @Synchro - I did have it set to 2 and it wasn't providing any additional useful information.  Your second comment isn't helpful.  I have had my code mirroring the PHPMailer example and many variations of it and the error remains.  I'm done with this setup.  I'm switching to an external mail provider.

Comment: From your code: `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;`, and I can tell it's set to that because there is no server-side output, only client, making it impossible for us to diagnose - if you don't show us that output, how do you expect us to help? You say it didn't provide useful info - but given you're having trouble understanding it, how do you know? I can also tell from your code that you started with a very old version of the gmail example, so it's likely you're using an old version of PHPMailer too. Getting grumpy with those that are trying to help you isn't an attitude that will get you very far.

Comment: I apologize.  I wasn't trying to be grumpy.  I am frustrated.  My point was that when it was set to 2, there wasn't any useful information coming back.  I also downloaded PHPMailer directly from Github for this effort so it was the latest version.  The point is moot however.  I am using Mailgun now with Curl.  Thanks for your efforts.  I think Google was shutting my server out completely due to the recent spam going out from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Test with G-suite account or sendgrid account. I have tested with my gmail credentials it works.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer; 
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'admin@gmail.com'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '123456789'; // SMTP password   
$mail->setFrom('admin@gmail.com, 'Krishna');
$mail->addAddress($to_addr, 'Test');     // Add a recipient
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body    = $message;
```

Comment: Please don't post code without explaining how it answers the question.

Comment: @Synchro please don't give any suggestions if you don't have any answers.. to post here

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question because the poster has not provided enough information to go on. When that's fixed, I may answer. in the mean time, unlike you I'm not posting guesses as answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a new Gmail account for the sole purpose of this project. I was facing the exact problem, apparently, Google doesn't let the server login to your account from some location very far away.
Creating a new account worked fine for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

        require ('../PHPMailerAutoload.php'); //add PhPMailerAutoload.php file Path
        $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create Object

        $name=$_POST['Name']; //get name from post method
        $to=$_POST['email']; //get email from post method
        $message    = $_POST['message']; //get msg from post method

        $mail->isSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the server
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
        $mail->Username   = "no-reply@mydomain.com";  // GMAIL username
        $mail->Password   = "*********";            // GMAIL password
        $mail->SetFrom('no-reply@mydomain.com', 'Jimmy');  //Set who the message is to be sent from
        $mail->Subject = "Email from Mailer";   // $this->subject;
        $mail->Body = "test Email msg";        // $this->message; 
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        $mail->addAddress($to,$name);
        $mail->WordWrap = 70;

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.'.'<br>';
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo);
            exit;

        } else {
            echo 'Message sent.'.'<br>';
            exit;
        }


    ?>
```